# Extracting date from string with non-standard structure

Tags: spss

In my dataset is birthdate a string.
It looks like that:

```
2003-03-01 00:00:00
```

I need that it to look like that:

```
2003.03.01
```

I have tried to change it in variable view and it did not worked out. Could you please help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to get SPSS to recognize the original date format in your string (anyone?) - so this is a workaround. The following command takes each element of the date from the string, turns it into a number, and inputs all three elements in a date creation command:

```
COMPUTE  NewDateVar = DATE.DMY(number(char.substr(yourvar,9,2),f4),
                               number(char.substr(yourvar,6,2),f2), 
                               number(char.substr(yourvar,1,4),f2)).
FORMATS  NewDateVar (SDATE10).
EXECUTE.
```